# How do i get grouped random numbers in different time intervals using php

Tags: php

I have failed to find any problem with my code, yet it only outputs numbers from 0 to 20 without following the time restrictions i imposed. Please help me out. Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    class random{
        var $max;
        var $min;
        function irregularnos($min,$max) {
             $num = '';
             $i = 0;
             $this->min=$min;
             $this->max=$max;
             while($i < 25)
             {
                 $num .= mt_rand($min,$max);
                 echo $num . "</br>";
                 $num = '';
                 $i++;
             }
         }
    } 
    $rand1 = new random;
    $rand2 = new random;
    $rand3 = new random; 
    $rand4 = new random;
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    $start_time = new DateTime(); //current time 
    while(true){
        if ($start_time->modify('+1 seconds')<= new DateTime() and  $start_time->modify('+2      seconds') > new DateTime()) { $rand2->irregularnos(21,50);}
else  if ($start_time->modify('+2 seconds') <= new DateTime() and $start_time-   >modify('+3 seconds') > new DateTime()) { $rand3->irregularnos(51,70);}
else if ($start_time->modify('+3 seconds') <= new DateTime() and $start_time->modify('+4 seconds') > new DateTime()) {$rand4->irregularnos(71,100);}
else if (new DateTime() < $start_time->modify('+1 seconds')) {$rand1->irregularnos(0,20);}
else if(new DateTime()> $start_time->modify('+4 seconds'))  { break;}
    } 
?>
```

Comment: It normally starts with indenting code.

Comment: you need to describe what you are trying to do and what exactly is broken for folks to help. might even figure out problem yourself that way!

Answer (score 0):

The code is working. Probably you are expecting the code to run *only once* per each random number, while in reality the loop may execute very many times, say, 50 times in the first second.

For that whole second, the condition that ensues is that time is between `start_time` and `start_time + 1 second`, so the 0-20 sequence is activated.

Also, note that you are not using properly your objects - for example, the instance variables min and max are never actually used, and your call prototype would make it pointless to declare four number generators.

This code has an added pause to show all the numbers being generated:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    class random{
        var $min;
        var $max;
        function __construct($min, $max) {
                $this->min = $min;
                $this->max = $max;
        }
        function irregularnos($n) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
                $num = mt_rand($this->min, $this->max);
                echo $num . '</br>';
             }
         }
    }
    $rand1 = new random(0,20);
    $rand2 = new random(21,50);
    $rand3 = new random(51,70);
    $rand4 = new random(71,100);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    $start_time = time();
    for($quit = false; !$quit;) {
        // How much time has elapsed since $start_time?
        switch(time() - $start_time)
        {
                case 0: $rand1->irregularnos(25); break;
                case 1: $rand2->irregularnos(25); break;
                case 2: $rand3->irregularnos(25); break;
                case 3: $rand4->irregularnos(25); break;
                default: $quit = true; break;
        }
        print "---\n";
        usleep(500000);
    }
?>
```